# Randomizing char array to display random password

Tags: c++, algorithm, passwords

I have been tasked with create a solution which will generate a secure password for the user.
i need to...

1. Prompt the user for the length of the password, the number of
   special characters along with the number of numbers.

   A password should then be generated randomly using those inputs.

for example output:

What’s the password length? 8

How many special characters? 2

How many numbers? 2

Your password is:
aun2$1s#

My level of programming is at a beginner stage here is and example of what i have done so far

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

void WorkoutPass(int ,int,int);

int passlength;
int specChar;
int number;


int main()
{
    cout << "Enter the length of password: ";
    cin >> passlength;


if (passlength > 0)
{
        cout << "Enter the amount of special characters: ";
        cin >> specChar;
        if (specChar > passlength)
        {
            cout << "Error - invalid value entered is above the length of password";
        }
        cout << "Enter amount of numbers";
        cin >> number;
        if (number > passlength)
        {
            cout << "Error - invalid value entered is above the length of password";
        }
        WorkoutPass(passlength, specChar, number);

}
else
{
    cout << "Error - invalid value entered password must be above zero";
}
return 0;
}


void WorkoutPass(int p, int s, int n)
{
string password;

char alphaBetArray[26] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
char specCharArray[10] = {'!','£','$','%','&','@','~','#','>','<'};
char numberArray[10] = {'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10'};


int numberOfLetters = p - s - n;


char letter;

// generate (numberOfLetters) letters

// each letter generated we add to the string
password += letter;

// Add special characters
// Add numbers



random_shuffle(password.begin(), password.end());

cout << password.c_str() << endl;
}
 void DisplayPass()
{

}
```

Comment: `'10'` is yukky. Did you mean `'0'`?

Comment: yea, sorry just notice that

Comment: @Bathsheba Incidentally '£' is also a wide character, so depending on your locale that should probably be replaced too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You "just" miss the random generation part, which you can get through the [rand](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/) function.
So in your case that will be:

```
for (int i=0; i<numberOfLetters; i++)
    password += alphaBetArray[rand()%sizeof(alphaBetArray)];
for (int i=0; i<s; i++)
    password += specCharArray[rand()%sizeof(specCharArray)];
for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    password += numberArray[rand()%sizeof(numberArray)];
```

Be sure to check in the input also the sum of special chars and numbers, now you just check the single entries but someone could put: 10 (password length), 6 (special chars), 7 (numbers), and that's bad.

Comment: [STL](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Speakers/Stephan-T-Lavavej)'s talk on why `rand` is a bad option after [tag:c++11]: https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful

Answer (score 1):

[c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) has introduced [`sample`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sample) Which you'll want to use along with the `random_shuffle` you already have in place to generate `password`:

```
random_device rd;
mt19937 g(rd());
auto it = sample(cbegin(alphaBetArray), cend(alphaBetArray), begin(password), numberOfLetters, g);

it = sample(cbegin(specCharArray), cend(specCharArray), it, s, g);
sample(cbegin(numberArray), cend(numberArray), it, n, g);
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/0qzEEqeVUI1JudIj)

---

A couple notes:

1. Your arrays are not comprehensive, writing a lambda to randomly generate characters in a range may be a preferable option, you could do that using [`generate_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate_n).
2. `random_shuffle` was deprecated in [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) you need to use [`shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) now

Answer (score 0):

1. Generate p random chars
2. Generate s special chars
3. Generate n random numbers
4. Concatenate them and shuffle them

```c
string workout_pass(int p, int s, int n)
{
  string password;

  const char alphaBetArray[26] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
  const char specCharArray[10] = {'!','£','$','%','&','@','~','#','>','<'};
  const char numberArray[10] = {'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10'};


  int numberOfLetters = p - s - n;

  for (i = 0 ; i < numberOfLetters; ++i ) {
    password += alphaBetArray[rand() % 26];
  }

  for (i = 0 ; i < s; ++i ) {
    password += specCharArray[rand() % 10];
  }

  for (i = 0 ; i < n; ++i ) {
    password += numberArray[rand() % 10];
  }

  random_shuffle(password.begin(), password.end());

  return password;  
}
```

Some comments :

1. Since it is a function it is better not to use CamelCase
2. Since it is a function you better return the generated string and not void
3. Try to get rid of the char arrays and play with ascii numbers (like 97 + (rand() % 26)) for [a-z]
4. Last but not least better use C with these problems not C++/STL functions like random_shuffle and try to achieve the same result, you will learn best that way

Comment: [STL](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Speakers/Stephan-T-Lavavej)'s talk on why `rand` is a bad option after [tag:c++11]: https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful

Comment: I don't get why use overly complex solutions for a simple problem, again he could go to an extreme and use Mersenne Twister with an astounding 2^19937−1 period, would he see any difference to his exercise ? Nope. Context people.

Comment: I linked the video so you *could* understand why. `rand` should only be used in pre-[tag:c++11] contexts. Which the OP is not using cause he calls `random_shuffle`. As to your question: "Would he see a difference?" The answer is yes. And certainly yes if you're not seeding your `rand`.

Comment: _My level of programming is at a beginner stage here is and example of what i have done so far_. But again is he going to use this code for a commercial application ? I saw the video and that's why I was annoyed. You **don't** need to know the existence of RNG at this level of programming.

For the `srand()` I was typing it fast and yes I know i forgot it, I'm gonna edit this later.

Comment: My reason for pointing out the problems with `rand` are exactly as you say, a beginning programmer shouldn't be bogged down with random number generator comparisons at this point. So let's start him out on the correct path. `mt19937` is just as simple as `rand` but more clear-cut in that functions like `sample` and `shuffle` handle all the moding and such for you.

Comment: Don't get me wrong I agree with your reasoning, I just totally disagree presenting a codegolf like solution (however clever or robust) to a novice. He might learn STL maybe after he learns how to use a class.